# Built-in Audio Analog Stereo is Switching Plugged-in to Unplugged

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Recently the audio on an Ubuntu desktop keeps switching between "Line Out (Plugged In)" to "headphones".  I can manually switch the port to "Line Out (Unplugged)" and sound continues out of my speakers, as they are certainly plugged in, but this is a nuisance when volume switches back to Line Out (Plugged-in).  Volume control will trigger me and flip my sound back to headphone then back to line out plugged in, then back to headphones and etc.. etc.. etc..  I've switched speaker aux cables, same issues remain.

As mentioned above, even when Line Out (UNPLUGGED) is selected, sound works just fine.  How can I disable this 'smart switch' and just force Ubuntu/Sound to remember I only want Line Out (where it is plugged in or not) and can manually switch to headphones (if that is needed.)

TYVM.

[System]
OS:              Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish
Arch:            x86_64
Kernel:          5.15.0-33-generic
Desktop:         ubuntu:GNOME
Display Server:  wayland

[CPU]
Vendor:          GenuineIntel
Model:           12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12600K

Comment: Look at `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` shortly after the problem. Suspect intermittent disconnect & reconnect caused by bad cable, bad plug, bad jack physical hardware. Listen to something on headphones and wiggle the cable.

Comment: @waltinator  Thanks for the reply.  This log isn't showing anything out of the ordinary, but the sound continues to switch to headphone and pretends my Line out is unplugged (yet line-out works even when reporting unplugged.)

Comment: same here. journalctl shows nothing relevant to sound. Started to happen in the last ~2 weeks from kernel ~5.15.0-60-generic but only in 1 of 5 sessions. @waltinator did you find out something since yout post?